# How to get the logs of platform plugins in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am new to eclipse plugin development. I would like to customise some of the eclipse functionalities in my plugin. So I would like to know, what happens in the background when I do some operation in eclipse. For e.g., File->New->Project. I need the logs/Trace of which plugin/Class/Function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-debug <path to options file>` argument when you start Eclipse to specify the path of a debug options file which is used to enable various debug tracing options. You may also want to use the `-consoleLog` argument.

A example options file would be:

```
# Turn on debugging for the org.eclipse.ui plugin.
org.eclipse.ui/debug=true

# Show all jobs in dialogs and the progress view including the support jobs
org.eclipse.ui/debug/showAllJobs=true

# Report if a stale job was found
org.eclipse.ui/debug/job.stale=true
```

The `org.eclipse.ui/debug=true` line enables debugging for a particular plugin in this case `org.eclipse.ui`. The other lines enable individual debugging options.

There are hundreds of these options, by convention most plugins include a `.options` file in the plugin jar listing the options that the plugin supports.

As mentioned in the comments in recent releases of Eclipse the debug tracing options are also available in the Preferences in 'General > Tracing' and on the Tracing tab of Launch Configurations.

You can also use 'plug-in spy' to find out the class which is displaying a dialog. Once this is installed you can press Alt+Shift+F1 when a dialog is displayed to get information. If you have the Eclipse source code plugins installed you can then go directly to the source code. For more information see [Eclipse Source Code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html) tutorial.

Comment: The tracing options can also be controlled through the UI. Either in _Window_ > _Preferences_ > _General_ > _Tracing_ for the running instance or in the _Tracing_ tab of PDE launch configurations for Eclipse applications launched from within the IDE.

Comment: Thank you @greg.  I tried the steps told by you. Somehow I could not able to get any logs/trace.  It would be great if you explain me with an example say File->New->Project.

Comment: +1 @Herrmann. I followed your steps also but no result. It would be great if you brief me with an example and how exactly tracing is shown in eclipse.

Comment: Well first you will have to identify what traces you want, as I said there are hundreds of options. You can only really do this by studying the source code. These options are not an easy way to see what happens when you do some particular action.

Comment: Personally I usually use plug-in spy to find the class displaying a dialog and then either just read the source or use debug to trace through the code.

Comment: Also your question talks about customizing Eclipse functionality - this is normally done through extension points and APIs. If there isn't an extension point or API it will be very difficult to change things. Perhaps you should ask a new question about exactly what you want to do.

Comment: +1 @greg. I would like to customize Siemens Teamcenter which uses eclipse rcp as underlying platform. So I thought of going through how exactly platform jars behave when we do some operation, as it would be easy for me to develop new plugins. I would appreciate your efforts in making me understand. It would be great if you give me some feedback on whether my approach is correct or not. Your inputs will be really helpful.

Comment: This is getting too broad for Stack Overflow. Tracing is designed for debugging problems, the output generally assumes that you already know what is going on.