# Why does Eclipse for C/C++ Developers not give console output when it builds?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Apparently, I changed some configurations in Eclipse so that it does not give any Console output when it builds any programmes.

So now I don't know if my C++ code compiles or not. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Java code? If yes, a plain Java, Maven, Gradle, etc. project?

Comment: This seems to be normal behaviour to me. Errors are shown graphically, in the source or in the problem view. Did it behave differently before? Also, are we talking about Eclipse for Java here, or some other language/plugin?

Comment: @howlger no, it is a C++ code. Any ideas?

Comment: @tobias_k I do not think it is normal..it should give me some feedback in the console..

Comment: Please expand your question about what kind of project it exactly is (CMake or ...?).

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Build Automatically` option in `Project->Build Automatically` to make sure your source code is getting compiled automatically. To know if there are any compile time issues; eclipse underlines the code in red color.
Hope it helps.

**Updates**
 1. By following your comments I figured out you just want to enable logging for the build process, fair enough.
 2. Eclipse doesn't do that by default. I must agree with @tobias_k. Whereas STS (Spring Tool Suit: enhanced version of eclipse for Java development) dose it.
 3. I also ran into [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173448/how-to-get-the-logs-of-platform-plugins-in-eclipse) which might help you or you could look for how STS does it.
Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thx for the help. The [Build Automatically] is already choosed. But there is now nothing showed in the eclipse Console.

Comment: @DexterLiu could you please provide the screenshot of your console settings: Windows-> Preferences-> in the search bar type console

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have added pitctures in the quesion

Comment: @DexterLiu, That looks good. One last question. Are you able to see the logs/output of your program on the console when you run it?

Comment: I can see the outputs after running the program. But I cannot see the "Build success" sign of the build nor the compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in default output folder **src/bin** whether .class is available for the compiled classes