# Find out what changed resources caused a workspace refresh/rebuild in Eclipse with Buildship

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

Is there a way to get more detailed logging output from the Eclipse platform or the Buildship plugin (or even through the Gradle API itself) with regards to what caused a project to be rebuilt?

### Context:

We are currently migrating from *Eclipse Mars (with Spring Gradle plugin)* to *Eclipse Photon (with Gradle Buildship plugin)*. One problem we encounter with the new version is that it ends up rebuilding large parts of the workspace every time we open Eclipse, which may take several minutes in large projects. `Refresh workspace on startup` is disabled in the Eclipse preferences. Setting `Max simultaneous project builds` to a higher value and `Max iterations when building with cycles` to a lower value than the defaults help mitigate the problem a bit by speeding up that initial rebuilt, but in the end it only works around the actual issue.

We did not have these problems in the old version and this behavior seems weird to me. After fully building the workspace, closing Eclipse and reopening it, I would expect that no resources changed and there is no need for a rebuild.

While we do have quite a few custom Gradle plugins and tasks, there are no *obvious* offenders, like tasks that generate sources. I do not want to fully dismiss the possibility that something we customized is messing with a file while evaluating the Gradle projects, though.

Hence why getting more information about why the IDE/plugin believes that the project requires rebuilding would be really appreciated to get a starting lead.

The only setting I've found so far is `eclipse.log.level`, but that already defaults to `ALL`.

Comment: There is lots of tracing you can enable (see 'General > Tracing' in the Preferences), but which tracing to enable would probably require studying the source code.

Comment: I do not have any Tracing options in my preferences. Does this perhaps require a certain plugin to be installed?

Comment: The whole page is missing.

Comment: The page is provided by the `org.eclipse.ui.trace` plugin but I thought that was included in all Eclipse installs

Comment: Then the blame is probably on me, since I uninstalled some preinstalled plugins that we don't need, to make our internal distribution as lightweight as possible.

Comment: You can also enable tracing using the `-debug` command line option see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173673/2670892)

Comment: Hmm, just checked a fresh "Eclipse Photon for Java Developers" distribution package and it does not seem to include the tracing page by default either. That page seems to come from a subcomponent of Equinox.

Comment: It looks like the plugin is only included in the Eclipse PDE feature which will only be in plugin development oriented packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding an `.options` file with

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.jdt.core/debug/javadelta=true

org.eclipse.core.resources/build/delta=true
org.eclipse.core.resources/refresh=true
```

to the installation directory of Eclipse. Then I launched Eclipse with the `-debug -consoleLog` arguments. Basically as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173673/7024019).

The configuration via tracing plugin didn't really work out in my case, since no log output was created. Might have been some problem on my end.

---

The resulting trace output in the console was enough to indicate a problem where the Gradle output directory for .class files did not match up with what Eclipse expected to be the output directory, so it probably treated the folder as just another bunch of resources.

It also showed that the resolved classpath of each project was marked as changed on each project right after opening Eclipse. Not sure yet if the first issue is the cause of the second.

Answer (score 1):

For the topic of unnecessary building when starting Eclipse: you may want to update to Eclipse 2018-09 (see https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), which contains two fixes related to this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536990 which was specific to  Eclipse Photon

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525597 which is an old problem that only appeared in larger workspaces (where it actually hurt the most)

Comment: Yeah, we actually found out about that bug as well and updated to the new version. And it did indeed fix our problems. (In context of the original question, the accepted answer is correct. But thanks for the hint anyway)